# Organizing images and text

Tags: css, grid, web-deployment

I am building a small web page as an exercise.
I'm trying to arrange three photos next to three texts aside each other and it's not working.
My idea is that they look like this:

```
                Photo---> text
                text--->photo
                photo--->text
```

And for that I wrapped the package of images and text in a 
then in css I put this:

```
               .grid-wrapper {
                   display:grid;
                   grid-template-columns. auto auto auto;
                   grid-gap: 10px;
               }
```

And well it hasn't worked.
I appreciate your advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by using `grid` or `Flex`

**Grid Example**

```css
.parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 20px;
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
}
.parent:nth-child(even){
  direction: rtl;
}

.img, .text {
  height: 100px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="img">Photo</div>
    <div class="text">Text</div>
 </div>
  
 <div class="parent">
    <div class="img">Photo</div>
    <div class="text">Text</div>
 </div>
  
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="img">Photo</div>
    <div class="text">Text</div>
 </div>
  
</div>
```

**FlexExample**

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  gap: 20px;
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
}
.parent:nth-child(even){
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

.img, .text {
  height: 100px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="img">Photo1</div>
    <div class="text">Text1</div>
 </div>
  
 <div class="parent">
    <div class="img">Photo2</div>
    <div class="text">Text2</div>
 </div>
  
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="img">Photo3</div>
    <div class="text">Text3</div>
 </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: I must admit that I get a little scared when I have to work with flexbox, but you explained it very well, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Use grid to create two separate columns. I believe the only mistake you were making was creating three columns rather than the intended two.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 20px;
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
}

.img, .text {
  height: 100px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  
  <div class="img">Image</div>
  <div class="text">Text</div>
  
  <div class="text">Image</div>
  <div class="img">Text</div>
  
  <div class="img">Image</div>
  <div class="text">Text</div>
  
</div>
```